# How to overcome TrainingException when training a large model with Azure Machine Learning service?

Tags: python, azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I'm training a large-ish model, trying to use for the purpose [Azure Machine Learning service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/service/tutorial-train-models-with-aml#create-an-estimator) in Azure notebooks.

I thus create an `Estimator` to train locally:

```
from azureml.train.estimator import Estimator

estimator = Estimator(source_directory='./source_dir',
                      compute_target='local',
                      entry_script='train.py')
```

(my `train.py` should load and train starting from a large word vector file).

When running with

```
run = experiment.submit(config=estimator)
```

I get

> TrainingException:
>
> ====================================================================
>
> While attempting to take snapshot of
>   /data/home/username/notebooks/source_dir Your total
>   snapshot size exceeds the limit of 300.0 MB. Please see
>   http://aka.ms/aml-largefiles on how to work with large files.
>
> ====================================================================

The link provided in the error is likely [broken](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/26076). 
Contents in my `./source_dir` indeed exceed 300 MB.
How can I solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can place the training files outside `source_dir` so that they don't get uploaded as part of submitting the experiment, and then upload them separately to the data store (which is basically using the Azure storage associated with your workspace). All you need to do then is reference the training files from `train.py`.

See the [Train model tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/service/tutorial-train-models-with-aml) for an example of how to upload data to the data store and then access it from the training file.

Comment: Hi Vlad, I am trying to Register a large model from a Datastore instead of uploading it locallt - do you have any advice on this? - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58061189/how-to-register-a-local-model-of-900mb-in-azure-machine-learning-service-with-cl

Answer (score 0):

After I read the GitHub issue [Encounter |total Snapshot size 300MB while start logging](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/26076) and the offical document [Manage and request quotas for Azure resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/service/how-to-manage-quotas) for Azure ML service, I think it's an unknown issue which need some time to wait Azure to fix.

Meanwhile, I recommended that you can try to migrate the current work to the other service [Azure Databricks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-databricks/), to upload your dataset and codes and then run it in the notebook of Azure Databricks which is host on HDInsight Spark Cluster without any worry about memory or storage limits. You can refer to [these samples](https://github.com/Azure/MachineLearningNotebooks/tree/master/how-to-use-azureml/azure-databricks/amlsdk) for Azure ML on Azure Databricks.

Comment: Thanks! While this might be buggy behavior, the accepted answer made me avoid the error in the question. While Databricks is a cool alternative I wanted to explore Azure ML service.