# How to register a local model of 900mb in Azure Machine Learning Service with CLI or SDK

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

I have a 900mb model and a 9mb model.

I am using the latest version of the Azure ML CLI to register it in my workspace with this command:

```
az ml model register -n "rj-model" --model-path "models\model_v1.bin -t "model-deployment\model.json"
```

The 9mb file uploads successfully however the 900 mb file times out with this error:

```
{'Azure-cli-ml Version': '1.0.60.1', 'Error': AzureHttpError('Operation could not be completed within the specified time. ErrorCode: OperationTimedOut\n<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Error><Code>OperationTimedOut</Code><Message>Operation could not be completed within the specified time.\nRequestId:2822b750-801e-0061-65fe-71aa88000000\nTime:2019-09-23T11:03:52.5521518Z</Message></Error>',)}
```

The UI has an even lower timeout threshold.

My thoughts on solving this:

- I need to upload the model to blob storage and access it from the cloud, not locally. I checked the [Model Register](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ext/azure-cli-ml/ml/model?view=azure-cli-latest#ext-azure-cli-ml-az-ml-model-register) method and it has an **--asset-path** property, however this is for an Experiment (I am not running experiments with AML - a Data Scientist is doing them in his own workflow and passing the models over to me for deployment).
- The DataStore looks promising and I could mount my model on a blob (after uploading it with Storage Explorer) and access it - however I can't seem to do this with the CLI. The Python SDK does have a dataset property but not a datastore property and the [Register method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-core/azureml.core.model.model?view=azure-ml-py#register-workspace--model-path--model-name--tags-none--properties-none--description-none--datasets-none--model-framework-none--model-framework-version-none--child-paths-none-) does not seem to have a cloud option.

So my question is: How can I register large models in Azure ML?

Comment: Latest azure-cli-ml is `1.0.62` per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/azure-cli-extensions-list?view=azure-cli-latest - can you update and see if that helps?

Comment: Yes, that fixed it - I updated the Azure CLI and Azure ML CLI to the latest and it worked. Thanks

Comment: I am also having this issue, though we much larger model related files. Is there currently no way to register a model folder directly from cloud storage ?